# Retrieving subsets of data with EUtilsGet

Tags: r, text-mining, pubmed

I am new to r and RISmed, so please accept my apologies if this is a very simple question.

I have been following a tutorial on how to get data on a large number of references from PubMed. When I use:

```
pubmed_data <-  data.frame('Title'=ArticleTitle(records),'Abstract'=AbstractText(records))
head(pubmed_data,1)
```

It returns the data for Title and Abstract as expected, however when I add instructions to return Author, Journal, Year, Country and Keyword it still only returns the Title and Abstract. What am I missing? I use the following code:

```
pubmed_data <- data.frame('Title'=ArticleTitle(records),'Abstract'=AbstractText(records), 'Journal'=Journal(records), 'Year'=DateCreated(records), 'Author'=AuthorList(records), 'Country'=Country(records), 'Keyword'=KeywordList(records))

head(pubmed_data,1)
```

Comment: Where do functions `DateCreated`, `Agency`... Come from? They don't appear in the RISmed reference manual.

Comment: The DateCreated comes from the PubMed help for tags on the official website. The Agency function that you write, is not in the text I posted.

Comment: Gah, I meant `Journal` and the rest.

Comment: This tutorial (http://amunategui.github.io/pubmed-query/) is the source code.                                                                                                                         
> search_topic <- 'copd'
search_query <- EUtilsSummary(search_topic)                                                                                    records<- EUtilsGet(search_query)                                                                > pubmed_data <-data.frame('Title'=ArticleTitle(records),'Abstract'=AbstractText(records))

Comment: Following the link posted to the NIH/PubMed help page, I used the pages listed there to attempt to pull out that information.

Answer (score 0):

Next to `ArticleTitle` and `AbstractText` functions, you're also using `Journal`, `DateCreated`, `AuthorList`, `Country`, and `KeywordList`. Some of these functions are not listed directly in the [package reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RISmed/RISmed.pdf) (only `Country` appears to be a valid function).